Difference between Lipchitz and Absolutely continuous functions
Def(1)[Absolutely Continuous]
Let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$,
$f \in AC(I)$ iff
$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta_{\epsilon}>0$ t.c. $\big(\forall $finite collection$ \{(a_i, b_i) \}^N_{i=1} $of disjoint intervals t.c. $(a_i, b_i)\subset I \,\forall i $ and $ \sum_i^N|a_i-b_i|\leq \delta_{\epsilon}\, \implies \sum_i^N|f(a_i)-f(b_i)|\leq \epsilon\big)$
An interesting, and non-evident, observation is that the disjointness condition play a crucial rule on this definition. Indeed we have the follwing result:
Thm[Lip Characterization]
Let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$,
$f \in \mathcal{Lip}(I)$ iff
$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta_{\epsilon}>0$ t.c. $\big(\forall $finite collection$ \{(a_i, b_i) \}^N_{i=1} $of intervals t.c. $(a_i, b_i)\subset I \,\forall i $ and $ \sum_i^N|a_i-b_i|\leq \delta_{\epsilon}\, \implies \sum_i^N|f(a_i)-f(b_i)|\leq \epsilon\big)$
$\Rightarrow$ is trivial to prove.
My attempt to $\Leftarrow$ implication is the following:
Let $x, y \in I$, we choose as finite collection $N$ times the same interval $\{(x, y)\}_{i=1}^N$, and  fix $\epsilon = \tilde\epsilon$, such that $N|x-y|\leq \delta_{\tilde\epsilon}$ and $N|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \tilde\epsilon$
Now we choose $N = \lceil \frac{\delta_{\tilde\epsilon}}{2|x-y|}\rceil \geq \frac{\delta_{\tilde\epsilon}}{2|x-y|}$, then $\frac{\delta_{\tilde\epsilon}}{2}\leq N|x-y| \leq \delta_{\tilde\epsilon}$
Then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \frac{\tilde\epsilon}{N} \leq 2 \frac{\tilde\epsilon}{\delta_{\tilde\epsilon}}|x-y|$
By arbitrary of $x, y \in I$ we can conclude the thesis. $\blacksquare$
My question is if it seems an a good prove of the thm.

It is correct. BTW, this has been answered before on MSE.
